# Why Jboss cares about war file name?

Tags: java, jboss

I took working existing project and renamed war built by IDE (notice: I didn't rename anything in file-system "by hand"). I renamed it from `jboss-as-helloworld-ws.war` to `book-store`

[image]

And I received exception during build:

```
18:55:11,436 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."jboss-as-helloworld-ws.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jboss-as-helloworld-ws.war".STRUCTURE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "jboss-as-helloworld-ws.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018740: Failed to mount deployment content
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.DeploymentRootMountProcessor.deploy(DeploymentRootMountProcessor.java:92) [jboss-as-server-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/sergei-rudenkov/SEPH/jboss-qs/helloworld-ws/target/jboss-as-helloworld-ws.war (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.vfs.spi.RootFileSystem.openInputStream(RootFileSystem.java:57)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.openStream(VirtualFile.java:238)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mountZipExpanded(VFS.java:567)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentMountProvider$Factory$ServerDeploymentRepositoryImpl.mountDeploymentContent(DeploymentMountProvider.java:97) [jboss-as-server-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.DeploymentRootMountProcessor.deploy(DeploymentRootMountProcessor.java:88) [jboss-as-server-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
    ... 6 more
```

Why does Jboss care about `*.war` file name? Where is config to change name?

Comment: which ids you are using ? Are you deploying on JBoss from IDE directly or deploying it from JBoss Console

Comment: I deploy from Idea. And it works perfect when I use for deploy "old" artifact name.

Comment: I guess then it is your IDE which is creating this problem to confirm it .. try deploying your war direct from JBoss console